# How to trigger teardown step if any of the previous job fails?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab CI as below:

```
# Workflow is configured for the pipeline to run as a branch pipeline when the branch is pushed,
# but the MR is not yet created, and run the pipeline on the merge result with the main branch when associated MR is already created
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" # For pipelines created by using Run pipeline button in the GitLab UI, from the project’s CI/CD > Pipelines section.

stages:
  - code-analyze
  - build
  - integration-test
  - performance-test
  - teardown

.base:
  tags:
    - gitlab-runners-220707-195833-small

check-style:
  extends: .base
  stage: code-analyze
  script: ./gradlew styleCheck

build-code:
  extends: .base
  stage: build
  script: ./gradlew build -x detekt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/authentication/build/libs/A.jar
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/collector/build/libs/B.jar
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/configuration/build/libs/C.jar
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/combiner/build/libs/D.jar

run-integration-test:
  extends: .base
  stage: integration-test
  before_script:
    - . ./CI/assume_role.sh
    - . ./CI/authentication.sh
  script:
    - . ./CI/.variables
    - export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh && nvm use 18
    - . ./terraform/test_apply.sh -w ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR && ./gradlew integrationTest
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  needs:
    - build-code

run-performance-test:
  extends: .base
  stage: performance-test
  before_script:
    - . ./CI/assume_role.sh
    - . ./CI/authentication.sh
  script:
    - cd $CI_PROJECT_DIR && ./gradlew gatlingRun -Dusers=500 -DbatchSize=500
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - performance-test/build/reports/gatling/
    expire_in: 1 week
    expose_as: 'gatling-report'
    when: always
  needs:
    - run-integration-test

.teardown: &teardown
  extends: .base
  stage: teardown
  before_script:
    - . ./CI/assume_role.sh
  script:
    - . ./terraform/test_destroy.sh -w ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
success-teardown:
  when: on_success # Run the job only when no jobs in earlier stages fail or have allow_failure true
  <<: *teardown
failure-teardown:
  needs: ["run-integration-test", "run-performance-test"]
  when: on_failure # Run the job only when at least one job in an earlier stage fails. A job in an earlier stage with allow_failure true is always considered successful.
  <<: *teardown
```

I have two teardown steps:

- `success-teardown` is supposed to run if all the previous stages are successful
- `failure-teardown` is supposed to run if `run-integration-test` fails or `run-performance-test` fails.

However failure-teardown is not working as intended and gets skipped when `run-integration-test` or `run-performance-test` fails. The teardown steps would also need jar artifacts from `build-code`. Does it automatically download jar artifacts if its in path or I need to add a dependency in teardown for `build-code`. Any help in this regard would be appreciated thanks.